# Filtering more than one term in a taxonomy in WP

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, events

i have a custom post type called 'events', it has a taxonomy named 'category' structured this way:

hotels (parent)
  -1 star   (child)
  -2 stars  (child)
  -3 stars  (child)
location (parent)
  -loc1     (child)
  -loc2     (child)
  -loc3     (child)
how do i filter, for example, only the events that belong to 1 star and, at the same time, to loc1 (basically the intersection of 1 star and loc1)?

Comment: Hi Andrellibus, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tax_query and use the AND condition:
Reference: [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) under Taxonomy Parameters

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'hotels',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( '1 Star' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'loc1' )
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```